# How to change the default keyboard for gnome?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Gnome apparently doesn't listen to the contents in /etc/default/keyboard
While a simple desktop manager like openbox does follow this, 
for new  users that is.

It is possibly a system on which gnome depends, because I tried a "apt purge gnome" to get all the settings away, but still: a new user gets the keyboard layout from the initial setup in gnome after gnome is reinstalled.

Thus How to change the default keyboard for gnome?

Comment: Did you try settings - Region & languages, input sources?

Comment: The default keyboard settings for GNOME, which for instance control the effective layout on the login screen, are saved in `/etc/default/keyboard`. (Possible user specific settings are stored in `~/.config/dconf/user`.) So I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I delete the homedir of a user and let pam_mkhomdir.so create a new one on login and  he still gets the old keyboard layout, not the one stored in /etc/default/keyboard.
But only in the gnome desktop environment.
People log in via sssd/ldap and then new homedirs are created and they get the keyboard setup as defined during installation, not the one in /etc/default/keyboard
The keyboard layout for gnome at installation is thus saved somewhere else, I would like to know where and how to change it.

Comment: Yes I could do that, @vanadium, but the intention is that someone logs in with sssd and the keyboard layout is like the one connected to the computer, as defined for the login screen.

Comment: Perhaps then edit your question, and especially the title, to clarify, because this is not anymore related to your desktop environment.

Comment: @vanadium, it is related to the desktop environment: openbox follows what is in /etc/default/keyboard but gnome not, there is some place where a default setting is kept for gnome, where the gnome desktop reads and applies to any new user/ new homedir config.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


I would like to know where and how to change it.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson the ~/.config/dconf/user is not an entirely bad idea, it actually works when I copy this from a user with "correct" keyboard layout to /etc/skel/.config/dconf/user and new users, get then all the settings, including the keyboard layout from that template user. 
I consider this a workaround however.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Your solution to copy ~/.config/dconf/user, from a prepared template user, as  root,  to /etc/skel/.config/dconf/user is actually a good working one. If you turn it into an answer, I'll accept it.
Thanks

Comment: @jringoot: I'm glad that my hint lead you to a working solution. But it's actually your solution, not mine, and I'd suggest that you submit it as an answer yourself. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. :) Then, after a couple of days, you'll be able to accept it to mark the question solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the aid of @GunnarHjalmarsson :
Usersettings are stored in:

> ~/.config/dconf/user

for custom user settings
I modified a template user and copied the

> ~/.config/dconf/user

to

> /etc/skel/.config/dconf/user

Now all new users have the settings as defined by the template user, including the keyboard, before the copy of it's

> ~/.config/dconf/user

I consider this a workaround/worksforme